# VBA code not working in slideshow mode

Tags: vba, powerpoint, slideshow

I have this piece of code, it increases the value of a textbox in the current slide. Works fine in normal view, but for some reason in slideshow view, doesn't work at all, whats wrong with it?

```
Sub Label1Plus1()
Dim sld As Long

sld = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex
ActivePresentation.Slides(sld).Shapes("textbox1").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ActivePresentation.Slides(sld).Shapes("textbox1").TextFrame.TextRange.Text + 1

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you getting any specific error? Is `ActiveWindow` what you expect it to be? Can you not get slides by name rather than by index (not familiar with PPT object model)?

Comment: I don't get any errors, i searched thoroughly and I can't  find another way to refer to the current active slide (I'm a new to VBA). But you got a point, maybe the problem is related to ActiveWindow

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I've answered the main question below but in answer to your question, you can access slides or shapes by name or by index. Index is generally more reliable UNLESS the user or other code might rearrange shape/slide order in ways your code can't predict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PPT won't show any error messages about errors in VBA code when you're in slide show view.  That's why you're not seeing any errors, but if it did, you'd see an error when it hits:

```
sld = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex
```

You can't select anything in Slide Show view, so there can be no .Selection object.

Instead use this:

```
Dim Sld as Slide
Set Sld = SlideShowWindows(1).View.Slide.Shapes("mytextbox")
```

Or if you prefer to use Sld as a Long variable

```
Sld = SlideShowWindows(1).View.Slide.SlideIndex
```